# Can chrome-extesnion work differently for different systems ? (Ex. apple silicon Mac and Intel Mac)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, v8

Some of my clients are claiming that the chrome-extesion I provided works on Intel Macs but not on Silicon Macs. But I don't understand this. It was because there was no such issue in the v8 engine.

Assuming the chrome version is the same,
Excluding external factors such as thrid-party API integration not related to Chrome,
Can chrome-extesnion work differently for different systems (or architectures)?

For example,
In the same chrome extension source code, it works on Intel Mac, but does not work on Apple silicon MacBook.

I tried searching with keywords such as v8 architecture issue, but I couldn't find anything. I'd like to find a true or false proof of the problem.

Comment: In general, yes, though I don't know whether those two Mac systems can have different behavior (assuming everything else is the same)

Comment: What code doesn't work?

Comment: @NorioYamamoto the code that injects ES6 JavaScript into the homepage and makes it work. (not a backdoor). I'm sorry I can't show you the detailed code because I don't have my copyright.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Is there any way to prove to my clients that in general this is the case?

Comment: Anything can happen due to a bug in the browser or in the CPU.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You're not providing enough detail for a solid response. "My code doesn't work" is not a useful problem description. You'll need to show some actual code that exhibits the behavior, and precisely describe the way in which it's failing (e.g., does it produce any particular error message?).

Generally speaking, part of the point of the Web is that the client device doesn't matter: things should work everywhere. That applies to Chrome extensions as well.

That said, there are some cases where code can learn something about the device it's running on, and intentionally or accidentally behave differently. A common example is to show different UI depending on available screen resolution. So in particular if you're interacting with someone else's website, it may be that that website itself is different on some systems.

The most obvious way to create an Intel/Apple silicon Mac difference would be to look at the user agent string, but as far as I can tell that appears to be the same for both kinds of CPU. But I'm sure there are other ways for code to tell which hardware it's running on, e.g. the [`chrome.system.cpu`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/system_cpu/) API, or the relative performance difference of certain operations.

It is also *possible*, but rather unlikely, that you've discovered a Chrome bug. If you can identify a particular extension API (or code pattern) that isn't working correctly on arm64 Macs, then it would be useful to file a bug at [crbug.com/new](https://crbug.com/new) -- but that would have to include a specific repro case, not just "I wrote some code and that code isn't working, please fix".

As another very general (and hopefully obvious) statement: when you offer some software (whether it's a Chrome extension or anything else), and your users report that "it works on devices of type X but doesn't work on devices of type Y", then it's your responsibility to investigate the problem, which may well require getting your hands on a device of type Y, at least temporarily. It may be tempting to hide behind some defense like "someone on the internet said this isn't possible" or "must be a Chrome bug", but chances are that it is indeed your code that isn't robust enough.